# KendoUI - How to reference control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am handling the edit even via grid.bind:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    //  Dialog related
    var grid = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.bind("edit", function (e) {
        var datePicker = $("#EndDate").getKendoDatePicker();
        if (e.model.isNew()) {
            e.container.kendoWindow("title", "Add Something");
        }
        else {
            e.container.kendoWindow("title", "Edit Something");                             
        }
    });
});
```

The first time the event fires, the datepicker is a usable object.
Subsequent firing of the event has datepicker as undefined.

UPDATE: I also created a sample non-kendo page that does the same thing:

http://jsbin.com/uZEqiMo/1/edit?html,js,output

Can anyone explain what the difference is and what I can do in kendo-ui to get the reference every time?

Comment: On my side it always says -> false , false , false ...

Comment: And that means it is NOT undefined which means that I have a reference to the button each time. In my kendo script if I was comparing to undefined I would get false and then subsequent calls to edit would return true.

Comment: Okey I see taht but, how we should reproduce the problem?

Comment: Looking more at this if I remove the .getKendoDatePicker() and just check the jquery object returned it is always populated. This tells me it is something to do with the kendo function itself.

Comment: Try to use $('#dtName').data('kendoDatePicker') instead

Comment: Same behavior as before. First time through the object is there. Subsequent event firings yield undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying numerous ways of doing this I started looking more into the event argument that is passed into the edit event (and I am sure the other events). The solution is to find the control off of the event object passed in instead of trying to find it the grid. In my case the event object, named 'e', has a 'container' property. This 'container' property is actually a reference to the window (the popup dialog) and so calling jquery's find on this got it to work. Here is the updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    //  Dialog related
    var grid = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.bind("edit", function (e) {
        //  Note: getKendoDatePicker below you could be substituted with .data("kendoDatePicker") // Right way
        var datePicker = $(e.container).find("EndDate").getKendoDatePicker();

        // var datePicker = $("#EndDate").getKendoDatePicker(); - Wrong way
        if (e.model.isNew()) {
        e.container.kendoWindow("title", "Add Something");
        datePicker.enable(false);
    }
    else {
            e.container.kendoWindow("title", "Edit Something");
            datePicker.enable(true);
    }
    });
});
```